# How to disable an eventHandler in pyqt?

Tags: python, qt, event-handling, pyqt4

I need to disable the textChanged()-Signal of a QTextBrowser if I need to.

I want to do this because of this: Typing in a qtextbrowser, then through the connection of textChanged() in realtime formating the content, and re-setting it into the qtextbrowser triggers textChanged() and this again the realtime formatting ... infinite loop. So I need to disable that the formatting triggers textChanged().

How do I do this in pyqt4?

Comment: Do you mean you want to `ignore` the event?

Comment: yes probably. But not in general, only when the text changement is done by a specific function.

Comment: Hm i thinks it's that simple:

self.disconnect(self, SIGNAL("textChanged()"), self.bla)